# Spyder running code really slow on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, spyder

I am trying to run some python code on a workstation with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The workstation has a Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz × 16 processor, and all threads are activating and working. The problem is that I ran this code in windows (same machine) and it took 3 minutes to run running in Spyder, on Ubuntu running in Spyder it has been more than an hour, and the code hasn't finished running. Spyder is only using 8% of my total CPU power!!! and when I check system monitor only one thread is being used 100% and the rest either 0 or 1.**% where * is any integer from 0-9.

Seems like either Ubuntu or Spyder is not using the full potential of the CPU and I have no clue why. Hyperthreading is activated and all cores are being used by ubuntu.

edit: Ubuntu is using all threads, but python is not. In fact, Python is using only 1 CPU. I searched around the forums and found a thread of somebody who had the same problem 16 threads, only 1 being used. They fixed it by running this "os.system("taskset -p 0xffffffff %d"% os.getpid())" before your code. This didn't do it for me. This is driving me insane, I really need to use all cores or this workstation is less powerful than my $200 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try Continuum Intel’s Math Kernel Library (MKL). 
See [here](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/mkl-optimizations/).

Comment: that's $100... If It worked for free on Windows, why do I have to pay to run my code on ubuntu? I just noticed Python is using one thread only, that's why it is so slow.

Comment: Yes, but I installed it about 1 years ago, it says I have 1 month, but nothing happened then, after 1 month and this is free for 1 month anyway so it worth i try at least to be richer with one experience.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to use all cores though? that's what I don't get. Why is python only using 1 core? Anyway, I'll try using the MKL libraries. Thx

Comment: With MKL I guess you will, then you will have the info that this is something python-spyder issue and you can seek further, but till then you can use your machine-config efficiently, please inform what is the result, I will search for solution till then anyway.

Comment: Well that didn't solve it, Python is still using 1 core only... and yes my code is using the scipy and numpy libraries.

Comment: See this issue https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1274
You should report your issue to spyder mailing list, the developer is a very quick and helpful guy.